# Как установить/запустить Блейд-сервер без шаси

Tags: linux, windows, сервер, железо, blade

Нужен маленький сервер, и не хочеться заниматься покупкой шаси для одного блейд-сервера. Кто знает, как можно реализовать запуск и управление блейд сервером без шаси.

Comment: Не проще ли купить обычный системный блок с начинкой помощнее?

Comment: @Sheridan, мощный сервак не нужен, а деньги в пустую трати не особо хочеться. Вот как то так

Comment: Вполне может так получиться, что лезвие будет стоить дороже хорошего системника. Вам, кстати, под какие задачи?

Comment: @Sheridan, сервер нужен под маленькое бизнес-приложение. Оно настолько маленькое, что даже VDS хостинг брать стыдно, а сервак в будщем пригодиться. Как-то так

Comment: Dell PowerEdge R340 продается с рельсами 16гб 1х камень ксеон 8х слотов 2.4 под диски, 1х раид, 2х 1гб интерфейса - $1-1.2к 1U не полная длина

Comment: если не хочется тратить деньги - купи райзен и мелкий корпус.